# Repeating a MSON data structure with different values

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary, mson

I have many places in my API where I will need to describe a list of objects. Each object has the same keys / structure but different values. How can I tweak the values of each instance of some data structure while retaining all the original type, description, etc of the original structure?

for example if I had the following data structure `Restaurant`

```
# Data Structures
## Restaurant (object)
+ restaurant_name: McDonald's (string, required) - The name of this restaurant
+ years_of_operation: 54 (number, required) - The number of years since established
```

Then, let's say I want to instantiate several `Restaurant`s in a GET response like so:

```
### List all restaurants [GET /restaurants]

+ Response 200 (application/json)
    + Attributes
        + data (array)
            + (Restaurant)
            + (Restaurant)
                + restaurant_name: Bob Evans
                + years_of_operation: 23
            + (Restaurant)
                + restaurant_name: Eataly
                + years_of_operation: 16
```

the JSON body would look like this (note how `years_of_operation` for Bob Evans and Eatly are now numbers)

[image]

and the rendered documentation will only show this (the descriptions for `restaurant_name` and `years_of_operation` for Bob Evans and Eatly are now missing)

[image]

I thought that MSON would carry over those descriptions and type definitions. Otherwise, I have to update a description (or type, requirement, etc) everywhere that data structure is used... but I was under the impression this is a sort of problem MSON is supposed to solve? Am I doing something silly?

I'm posting here in addition to my [github issue](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson/issues/94) since it's been a long time since that repo has had contribution